# Allowing for Ajax calls on localhost using different ports

Tags: php, ajax, .htaccess

I am working on my current project two different installations of WAMP - one on my laptop, one on my PC. On my laptop, WAMP uses port :80, while on the PC it uses :8080.

Is there a way - either in my htaccess file, my routing controller, or otherwise to dynamically detect the current port and implement it correctly during ajax calls?

Currently, I build the url using the `window` object to detect the root of the project and the port. My ajax call is made to the resulting variable + `controller/method`, and includes the correct port (when not :80).

This results in `url: http://localhost:8080/mySite/controller/method`, yet throws the following error:

`XMLHttpRequest cannot load http://localhost/mySite/controller/method.`

The port is being ignored, or overwritten. I make no reference to ports in my .htaccess file, which is simply as follows:

```
Options -Multiviews

RewriteEngine On

RewriteBase /mySite/

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/api/.*$
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f

RewriteRule ^(.+)$ index.php?url=$1 [QSA]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In PHP you can detect the port being used on the user's machine to communicate with the web server with `$_SERVER['REMOTE_PORT'];`

in htaccess you have `%{SERVER_PORT}` available

Comment: How would I use that? My .htaccess file redirects everything after the root dir (e.g. `MySite`) to my routing controller as the `$url` variable, which therefore does not include the port. Should I rebuild the entire url again at that point to include it?

Comment: you have also SERVER_PORT available in htaccess you can use it with `%{SERVER_PORT}` :)